Would the electroweak interaction be possible in a space of odd dimension?
In order to describe well the electroweak interaction, chiral particle states are necessary. This works well in 4D (Minkowski) space, but it seems that it is not possible in a space of odd dimension (for instance in 5D or 7D, 9D or 11D etc.).
Because, in spaces of odd dimensions the projections of a Dirac-spinor onto Weyl-spinors are not possible, since a $\gamma$-matrix like $\gamma^5$ in 4D does not exist. For instance, in 5D, the Clifford-algebra needs a further gamma-matrix which is actually, in that case, $\gamma^5$. If one tries to build an equivalent of $\gamma^5$ in 5D one would try
$$\gamma^{5}_{5D} = i\gamma^0 \gamma^1 \gamma^2 \gamma^3 \gamma^5_{4D},$$
similar to how it is done in 4D. However, $\gamma^{5}_{5D}$ turns out to be multiple of $\mathbf{1}$, the unit matrix, and cannot therefore fulfil the purpose. Then operators like $(1\pm \gamma^5_{5D})/2$ make no sense anymore.
Therefore, I guess, a description of the electroweak interaction would not be possible. Is that correct? By the way, is this also the reason why 11D supergravity could not be really a successful theory, as it would not be able to incorporate the electroweak interaction in its respective matter gauge-field couplings?

If you define the EW interaction  as ineluctably chiral, then you cannot make it work in odd dimensions, since there are no Weyl spinors in  such dimensions. But why would you be interested in that? Reducing odd dimensions to even ones, through artful compactification, you may reintroduce nontrivial chirality.


In order to describe well the electroweak interaction chiral particle states are necessary.

The electroweak interaction is made of the $SU(2)\times U(1)$ gauge forces and the Higgs field, none of which are chiral. It couples to anything with electroweak charge. In our world there are chiral fermions with electroweak charge, but the electroweak force per se doesn't care about chirality. Your question seems to be just about the fermions.

If one tries to build an equivalent of $\gamma^5$ in 5D one would try $\gamma^{5}_{5D} = i\gamma^0 \gamma^1 \gamma^2 \gamma^3 \gamma^5_{4D}$ similar as it is done in 4D. However, $\gamma^{5}_{5D}$ turns out to be multiple of $\mathbf{1}$, the unit matrix, and cannot fulfill therefore the purpose.

Your $\gamma^{5}_{5D}$ is just $(\gamma^{5}_{4D})^2 = 1$. The natural extension of $γ^5$ to 5 dimensions would be $γ^0γ^1γ^2γ^3γ^4$ or $iγ^0γ^1γ^2γ^3γ^4$, whichever one squares to $+1$. That can be used to project out chiral subalgebras.

That said, I think the sort of chiral fermions that you find in the Standard Model are only possible in 3+1, 7+1, 11+1, ... spacetime dimensions.
Weyl spinors are irreps of the even Clifford algebra, not the full algebra. (I.e., they are true spinors, unlike the Dirac spinors which are really pinors.) The even real Clifford algebra in 3+1, 7+1, 11+1, ... dimensions does not split into chiral halves, because the pseudoscalar has the wrong sign. It's isomorphic to a matrix algebra over $\def\R{\mathbb R} \def\C{\mathbb C} \def\H{\mathbb H} \C$, and it has a single $\C^2, \C^8, \C^{32}, \ldots$ spinor irrep, not a pair of Weyl spinor irreps. But the tensor product of that algebra with a similar complex algebra for the gauge group does split, essentially because $\C \otimes_{\R} \C \cong \C \oplus \C$.
The reason the Dirac algebra is complexified in QFT (genuinely complexified in the physical theory, not just mathematically complexified for the purpose of finding representations with a restriction to the real part in the end) is that Dirac fermions have a $U(1) \cong \text{Spin}(2)$ charge. The complexified Dirac algebra is $C\ell^+(\R^{3,1}) \otimes_{\R} C\ell^+(\R^2)$, and $C\ell^+(\R^2) \cong \C$. The pseudoscalars of $C\ell^+(\R^{3,1})$ and $C\ell^+(\R^2)$ each square to $-1$, but the pseudoscalar of the product algebra squares to $+1$, so it splits. The same thing happens for internal algebras $C\ell^+(\R^{4k+2}), k\in\mathbb N$, and $C\ell^+(\R^{10})$ is the smallest of them whose embedded Spin group contains a copy of the Standard Model group. That's why $\text{Spin}(10)$ grand unification is a thing (better known as $SO(10)$ grand unification).
In 1+1, 5+1, 9+1, ... dimensions, the even Clifford algebra of spacetime splits on its own. So you have chiral spinors, but not the funny correlation with the gauge group that you get in the Standard Model. (By "correlation" I mean that in 3+1, ... dimensions only certain combinations of spacetime and gauge rotations are allowed, those with the correct isoclinic parity. Does that mean I should have said the electroweak force is involved in chirality after all? I think not, because the entire gauge group is involved, not just the electroweak part. But I may be wrong.)
In odd total dimensions (0+1, 2+1, 4+1, ...), the even Clifford algebra doesn't split because there is no pseudoscalar in the algebra, and the tensor product with any internal algebra also has no pseudoscalar. In terms of the matrix algebras, the external algebra is isomorphic to a matrix algebra over $\R$ or $\mathbb H$, and combining with the gauge group doesn't help because $\{\R, \H\} \otimes_{\R} \{\R, \C, \H\}$ is a matrix algebra over $\R, \C,$ or $\H$, not a pair of them.
I know this is handwavy and I don't know how to make it less so.
I don't know the implications of this for 9+1 dimensional string theory or 10+1 dimensional supergravity. Probably none because it's only the 3+1 non-compactified dimensions that matter for spacetime chirality.

I don't really follow what's happening in the paragraphs after "When you complexify the Dirac algebra" - don't we just complexify all algebras when looking for their complex representations because that's easier? What is the gauge group doing here? What is the "similar complex algebra for the gauge group"? By Coleman-Mandula, there is no mixing between spacetime and internal (gauge) symmetry groups! The SO(10) from the SO(10) GUTs is just a gauge group and has nothing directly to do with spinors under the spacetime Lorentz group.

@ACuriousMind I rewrote/expanded some parts. I was talking about the complexified Dirac algebra that appears in the physical theory, whose phase is the U(1) gauge phase. I changed "mixing" to "correlation" and tried to clarify what I mean by that. Another way of saying it is the Weyl field has no C or P symmetry but does have the combined symmetry. Coleman-Mandula may be related to the combined algebra being $C\ell^+(\mathbb\R^{3,1}) \otimes_{\mathbb\R} C\ell^+(\mathbb\R^2)$ and not $C\ell^+(\mathbb\R^{3,1} \times \mathbb\R^2)$.

The post goes beyond my understanding. I have no idea at all what "you complexify the Dirac algebra". I thought, there would only the Clifford algebra.

I've now tried to understand what this answer is talking about several times, but I still cannot decipher it. What does the EM U(1) have to do with the "complexified Dirac algebra", and, in turn, what does that have to do with the question whether chiral electroweak theory (with gauge group SU(2) x U(1)!) exists in odd dimensions. Changing the word "mixing" to "correlation" still did nothing to explain what you're really talking about here. Also, that all Dirac fermions have electric charge is just a specialty of the Standard Model, this answer somehow sounds as if that were more fundamental.
